# Large Panda column read and add column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Currently using pandas with python to load a large CSV file. I'm struggling to efficiently create and add a new column based on multiple values in three columns from the dataframe.

There are three columns (time, CO2 and cost) and I want to add a new column called gcost based on some calculations

The code below works but it's very slow. I believe it is the items `row['time']` that slows it down:

**Input**

```
Id,time,CO2eq,cost

0,10,10,10

1,5,5,5

2,2,3,6
```

**Expected Result**

```
Id,time,CO2eq,cost,gcost

0,10,10,10,X

1,5,5,5,X

2,2,3,6,X
```

**Code**

```
#wftime, wfco2eq and wfcost are inputted from the front-end.
    hhinfo_input_df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path, header=0,
                              names=['Id','CO2eq', 'time', 'cost'])

    hhinfo_input_df['gcost'] = hhinfo_input_df.apply(cost_generate, axis=1)
    return hhinfo_input_df

#Normalized weighted values of each criterion (input by user)
def cost_generate(row):
    Norm_time = (row['time'] * (wftime / max_time)) * 100000
    Norm_co2eq = (row['CO2eq'] * (wfco2eq / max_co2eq)) * 100000
    Norm_cost = (row['cost'] * (wfcost / max_cost)) * 100000

    gcost = int(round(Norm_time)) + int(round(Norm_co2eq)) + int(round(Norm_cost))

    #gcost should never be 0.
    if gcost == 0:
        return 1
    return gcost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to perform these operations at the row level. Pandas will handle that much more quickly if you just use the vectorized version of these operations:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path, header=0,
                 names=['Id','CO2eq', 'time', 'cost'])

Norm_time = (df['time'] * (wftime / max_time)) * 100000
Norm_co2eq = (df['CO2eq'] * (wfco2eq / max_co2eq)) * 100000
Norm_cost = (df['cost'] * (wfcost / max_cost)) * 100000
df["gcost"] = Norm_time.round().astype(int) + Norm_co2eq.round().astype(int) + Norm_cost.round().astype(int)
```

Comment: Won't that change the default values? I've also made a mistake and missed out 2 lines. gcost should never be 0 (apologies!).

Comment: All sorted. That made it instant (took 11 seconds previously). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using all your formulas in one shot?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ ['A',2,1], ['B',1,3] ]

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['ID','Item1','Item2']

dataset['total'] = dataset['Item1'] + dataset['Item2']
```